# Converting String to int array, java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6

Tags: java, arrays, exception, user-interface, indexoutofboundsexception

Here is a little snippet of my code, which is attempting to convert a length 6 string into an int array.

```
int[] intArray=new int[6];
int i = 0;
String s = jTextField2.getText();
int strLength = s.length();
if(strLength != 6) {
  jTextArea1.setText("Not a valid length");
} else {
  for(i=0;i<6;i++) {
    intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
  }
}
```

This comes up with an out of bounds exception and I cant understand why.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the value of s?

Comment: The length of s is 6. eg: 123456

Comment: Looks like your code is ok, but jTextField2.getText() is returning null check that

Comment: Try with  jTextField2.getText().toString(). Just a suggestion

Comment: Oh, thats because I'm using a GUI. change that line to: String s = 123456;

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] intArray=new int[6];
  int i = 0;
  String s = "123456";
  int strLength = s.length();
  if(strLength != 6) {
    System.out.println("Not a valid length");
  } else {
    for(i=0;i<6;i++) {
      if (!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
        System.out.println("Contains an invalid digit");
        break;
      }
      intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
    }
  }
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray));
}
```

Prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

here.